# How to switch from AMD graphics to Intel without fglrx driver

Tags: ati

I am a pretty new linux user. So please be as descriptive as possible.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 with Radeon HD 5650 on my laptop. I can easily switch between these two in Windows. I want to be able to switch to Intel HD graphics because AMD causes heating problem and fan runs very noisy. In addition, it is my work computer and i won't be needing any graphics acceleration.

I have a problem with Catalyst driver. When I activate it, I get the error message "running in low graphics mode" on startup. Then I have to switch to the generic driver. I was working on this issue for weeks. I tried many things from the forums but I got nothing. I purged the driver and installed it from AMD website. I caused Linux to crash several times and re-installed it. So that I really don't want to deal with it much. I want to stay on the safe side. So please be sure that it is safe before posting.

I trieed:

```
sudo su -
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

and I got:

```
-su: /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch: No such file or directory
```

And there is no option about it in BIOS. What should I do to switch to intel HD graphics?

```
>>grep -i switcheroo /boot/config-*
/boot/config-3.8.0-29-generic:CONFIG_VGA_SWITCHEROO=y
/boot/config-3.8.0-31-generic:CONFIG_VGA_SWITCHEROO=y`

>>ls -l /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/
ls: cannot access /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/: No such file or directory

>>cat /etc/default/grub | grep CMDLINE
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

When I open Additional Drivers from "System Settings" it says:

```
No proprietary drivers are in use on this system. 
ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (**experimental**beta)
This driver is activated but not currently in use.
```

Comment: Please, execute `cat /etc/default/grub | grep CMDLINE` and add the information by **editing** your question.

Comment: [Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) says vga_switcheroo only works if you are using the open source driver(nouveau, radeon) and not the proprietary ones (nvidia, fglrx).